# Take array and push odd and even numbers into separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with one letter/two number formatted elements in it and need to split the elements in the original array into the other two arrays, by odd and even numbers, and keep the original array intact. I have looked through a lot of other questions here, but none seem to fit.

I have been looking at some javascript code that works when the array elements are numbers only, but it won't work with the leading letter added. Here is the code:

```
var h = [06, 03, 02, 13, 04, 05, 12, 07, 09, 01, 11, 22];

e = [];

for (var i = 0; i < h.length; ++i) {
    if ((h[i] % 2) == 0) {
        e.push(h[i]);
    }
}
alert(e);

o = [];

for (var i = 0; i < h.length; ++i) {
    if ((h[i] % 2) == 1) {
        o.push(h[i]);
    }
}

alert(o);
```

This works fine (even though it drops the leading digit if it is a zero), but now if the array is changed to

```
var h = [B09,O67,I21,B04,B13,N34,N43,O74,O75,I26];
```

The code above does not work with the new array. I figure that I would need to filter out the odds and evens by looking at only the last number of each element, but I have not been able to figure out how to do so. The array elements are all in the same three character format of one letter followed by two digits and would have to retain this same format in their new arrays.

Thanks for any direction in this and a Happy Thanksgiving to all,

Stan...

Comment: welll `var h = [B09,O67,I21,B04,B13,N34,N43,O74,O75,I26];` is not valid unless you are missing quotes. Trim off the letter, convert to a number, and do the odd/even check.

Comment: look @Stan, you will have to use parseInt to convert strings to integer values provided you have entered the elements in double quotes. You cannot enter a non-numeric value without quotes in a javascript array.

Comment: Agreed to both epascarello and Tanveer Shaikh. Just a little sloppiness in my trying to get this posted up here when I was rushed for time. Thanks to both, Stan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of :

```
h[i] % 2
```

You can just do :

```
parseInt(h[i].substring(1)) % 2
```

That is assuming you forgot the quotes in your example array, which should be :

```
var h = ["B09","O67","I21","B04","B13","N34","N43","O74","O75","I26"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at, and tried parseInt a little while before coming here, but had not been able to get the code set up right. This works fine except for one little glitch. I am on XP, which is tied into IE8, and when this is run on IE8, all numbers go to their proper respective odd or even arrays except B09. For some reason B09 always goes into the even array. No other number ending in 9 (19, 29, 39, etc) has this problem except 09. BTW, this code works excellent in FireFox, but it just has that "09" issue in IE8. Any thoughts on a possible IE8 workaround? Thanks again, Stan

Comment: Never mind, I answered my own question. I had to add ", 10" to specify base 10 to parseInt. For anyone else looking at this, the resulting code looks like this: ((parseInt(h[i].substring(1), 10) % 2) == 0) Now it works fine, even in IE8. Thanks again and have a great holiday to all, Stan...

Answer (score 3):

I won't duplicate what's already been said, but I will add that you should combine the 2 loops into just one:

```
e = [];
o = [];

for (var i = 0; i < h.length; ++i) {
    if (/* h[i] is even */) {
        e.push(h[i]);
    } else {
        o.push(h[i]);
    }
}

alert(e);
alert(o);
```

Comment: I agree with your thoughts here. I just had them split out during initial development to help keep things straight in my own mind. Thank you, Stan...